# Android ImageButton prevent background from resizing

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

**Situation**
I have a bunch of ImageButtons with ripple effects in my layout. For API < 21 i created selectors as a replacement of the ripples.

Ripple API < 21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_circle_red" android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

shape_circle_red

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="10dp"
android:shape="oval">
  <size
    android:width="20dp"
    android:height="20dp" />
  <solid android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>
```

ImageButton

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_red"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_button1" />
```

**Problem**
On API >= 21 the normal ripple works perfectly fine. But on API < 21 my self build ripple effect is being stretched to the size of the ImageButton. In other words, the circle shows up as an oval because width and height of my ImageButton are not equal.

**Question**
How can i keep my ripple from being stretched to the size of my ImageButton

**What i tried so far**
 - Setting my background as a drawable rather than via id
 - android:adjustViewBounds="false" on my ImageButton
 - android:scaleType="centerInside" on my ImageButton

Comment: What does _Setting my background as a drawable rather than via id_ mean? Do you mean setting background programmatically?

Comment: Have you tried using `AppCompatImageButton`?